# Bug / unclear behaviour in close review queue?

Tags: support

for this review: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/107409

To this question, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194144/far-cry-4-cross-compatibility-multiplayer

I try to select "Close", and select the duplicate, but I get the "does not have accepted or upvoted answer" -- fair enough.

But two people have already voted to close it as a duplicate of that question.

[image]

What causes this?

To clarify: I am not asking why I can't vote it as a dupe (I understand that logic), I'm asking how it seems other people have voted it a duplicate of the same post.

Comment: Not a bug; expected.  They changed [duping rules awhile back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question/165946#165946) to require an upvoted answer to actually vote to dupe.  It was...not well received here.

Comment: Hi @Frank sorry I was unclear in my question -- I understand that duping rule, I'm wondering how people have avoided it by VTC even though the question doesn't have an upvoted answer.

Comment: Our accepted? workaround.  Upvote answer.  Vote to dupe.  Unupvote answer.  Since it's your answer, you might have seen some rep pingponging.

Comment: Yeh, I didn't see any rep changes -- but that doesn't mean it didn't happen, I guess, if it happened entirely between visits.